# Encountered an unknown error (CocoaPods could not find compatible versions for pod

Tags: swift, cocoapods

I am in the process of creating a pod.
I am getting this error while linting :
**pod spec lint TrackerExample.podspec --no-clean --use-libraries**

I am 1 error away from pod validation. Can you please help figuring out what is missing or what requires revision.

this is my podspec:

```
Pod::Spec.new do |spec|
  spec.name         = "TrackerExample"
  spec.version      = "0.0.1"
  spec.license      = "Copyright ****"
  spec.homepage     = "https:// *****"
  spec.author       = { "*****" => "*******" }
  spec.summary      = "some description"
  spec.source   = { :git => "******t" }  
  spec.source_files  = "TrackerExample/*.{h,m}"
  spec.ios.deployment_target = "9.0"
  spec.osx.deployment_target = "10.10"
  spec.swift_version = '4.0'
  spec.dependency 'MatomoTracker', '5.2'
  spec.subspec 'MatomoTracker' do |lib|
    lib.dependency 'MatomoTracker', '5.2'
    lib.source_files = "Pods/MatomoTracker/MatomoTracker/*.{h,m,swift}"
  end
end
```

and, this is the terminal output. I am getting the following error:

```
ERROR | [OSX] unknown: Encountered an unknown error (CocoaPods could not find compatible versions for pod "MatomoTracker":




-> TrackerExample (0.0.1)
    - WARN  | source: Git sources should specify a tag.
    - WARN  | [iOS] license: Unable to find a license file
    - WARN  | xcodebuild:  MatomoTracker/MatomoTracker/EventSerializer.swift:15:19: warning: 'flatMap' is deprecated: Please use compactMap(_:) for the case where closure returns an optional value
    - NOTE  | xcodebuild:  MatomoTracker/MatomoTracker/EventSerializer.swift:15:19: note: use 'compactMap(_:)' instead
    - WARN  | xcodebuild:  TrackerExample/Pods/MatomoTracker/MatomoTracker/EventSerializer.swift:15:19: warning: 'flatMap' is deprecated: Please use compactMap(_:) for the case where closure returns an optional value
    - NOTE  | xcodebuild:  TrackerExample/Pods/MatomoTracker/MatomoTracker/EventSerializer.swift:15:19: note: use 'compactMap(_:)' instead
    - ERROR | [OSX] unknown: Encountered an unknown error (CocoaPods could not find compatible versions for pod "MatomoTracker":
  In Podfile:
    TrackerExample (from `/Users/s.ludosky/Documents/projects/ios/libs/TrackerExample/TrackerExample.podspec`) was resolved to 0.0.1, which depends on
      MatomoTracker (= 5.2)

Specs satisfying the `MatomoTracker (= 5.2)` dependency were found, but they required a higher minimum deployment target.) during validation.

Pods workspace available at `/var/folders/n8/9jmhgp1x2hxgg7_r4ryvs7tcn166k1/T/CocoaPods-Lint-20180821-86279-qyai9s-TrackerExample/App.xcworkspace` for inspection.

Analyzed 1 podspec.

[!] The spec did not pass validation, due to 1 error and 4 warnings.
```

something related to the podfile. I did specify the pod version as **5.2** though. Why is this conflicting with the version **0.0.1** of my own pod ?

fyi, this the podfile for the 'MatomoTracker' dependency I am using

```
# Uncomment the next line to define a global platform for your project
platform :ios, '9.0'

target 'TrackerExample' do
  # Comment the next line if you're not using Swift and don't want to use dynamic frameworks
  use_frameworks!

  # Pods for TrackerExample
  pod 'MatomoTracker', '~> 5.2'
end
```

Comment: Try `'5.2.0'` for the depedency?

Answer (score 1):

If you create a file called .swift-version with the version you need (e.g. "4.0"), in the same directory where you run pod spec lint
echo "4.0" > .swift-version

It may solve your problem.

Also just do the below steps:-

1. pod deintegrate
2. pod install
3. pod update (if it is necessary so do it else if you have all latest pod so don't use it.)

Comment: I am not quite sure what file .swift-version I need to create here

Comment: In your build setting swift 4 and above should be selected, please check. @sandraoo

Comment: I don't think this is it. My swift version is already 4.1 in the build settings.